# Delete files non-project files from SVN in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, svn, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn

I am using AnkhSVN in Visual Studio.

How can I delete all files from SVN as I delete them from Visual Studio (**files ARE NOT included in projects**).

Ideally I would like to do:

1. Press "Show All Files" In Visual Studio (shows the files not included in projects).
2. Delete selected files (the ones not included in projects) from VS Solution Explorer.
3. Commit (Deletes the files in SVN)

But this is not possible and I have to delete files directly from Repository OR delete missing files from TortoiseSVN.

Cheers,
Dmitriy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your scenario should work. What's wrong with deleting missing files using TortoiseSVN?

[TortoisSVN commit http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/5603/tortoisesvncommit.png](http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/5603/tortoisesvncommit.png)

Comment: Thanks. So I just have to rigt click on the missing files an delete them. After commiting they are gone.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do it is using explorer. You can add a column to explorer called SVN Status. You can then sort the file view using that and delete the ones that you don't want..

[image: Explorer Detail View]
<sub>(source: [tigris.org](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/images/ExplorerDetailView.png))</sub>

Comment: AFAIR, newer Windows versions don't allow to add custom columns, so you can't add Subversion-related info to Windows Explorer / File Explorer in Win8+

Answer (score 2):

I do not think AnkhSVN checks for files that are not in your project. Why don't you directly delete them in explorer using TortoiseSVN?

Comment: There are too many files and they are mixed with ones that ARE in project. So I just want to avoid possibility of making a mistake.

Comment: Then add them to the project then delete them.

Comment: But in this case I cannot distinguish which ones I have to delete. VS nicely highlights (by making them grayed) the files not in project.

Answer (score 1):

I either use a RapidSVN for that task, or add to VS Project (Add - Existing file) then delete, as Daniel says.